# aws cloudwatch logs filter pattern include lines before and/or after matching pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there a way to include N lines before and/or after a matching pattern in AWS CloudWatch Logs?

Let's say I have this query and would like 3 lines before and after each match.

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name my-group --filter-pattern "mypattern"
```

The only work around I have at the moment is to remove the filter pattern and use grep:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name my-group | grep -A 3 -B 3 mypattern
```

However, I would like to only stream the log events I need and do it as part of the aws log events query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is currently not supported by AWS ([confirmed by a contributor](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5008#issuecomment-591705400)), but there is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5008) for tracking the feature to potentially support this in the future.

In the meantime, you will have to resort to filtering after the logs are streamed as mentioned in the question.

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name my-group | grep -A 3 -B 3 mypattern
```

Comment: `-C 3` will do `-A 3 -B 3`

Comment: I think this is not really enough, first, when I do this I get JSON back, so the grep +/- rows doesn't work. Secondly, there needs to be some way to search "the last day" or something. Currently aws logs seems to only support entering en explicit MILLISECONDS SINCE 1970 as --start-time. It's like they have done this as human non-useable as possible :)

Comment: Some added hints to get this to work better: --output text outputs as text and not json (which seems to be the default). Do date +%s to get the unix current timestamp, subtract manually say 3600 for an hour, then do --starting-time <value + 000>

Comment: In the AWS SDK for .NET, the `AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient` class, in addition to the `FilterLogEvents` method, has the `StartQuery` method for running Insignts queries using Insights syntax. The latter might be a better feature to use for the search. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudWatchLogs/TCloudWatchLogsClient.html

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same problem, and found simply **searching by timestamp** solved my issue to some extent.

CloudWatch has "Logs Insights", which is a fluent log searcher.

Search by a keyword and get the timestamp, then filter nearby logs with the timestamp.

[image]

Comment: Logs Insights support math operations so if you know that timestamp of a specific record is X, you can do `filter @timestamp >= X - 1 and @timestamp <= X + 1`. This is useful when you searched for and copied X and may want to gradually increase the search range where you target event should be roughly in the middle of